# How to remove the two digit or one digit after the comma and the remaining character after that? -Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some list of numbers:
1,000,000,00
1,000,000,0
1,000,000,000
1,00,0000,000

The expected output:
 
1,000,000
1,000,000
1,000,000,000
1

So, when there are only two digits and one digit after the last comma, the digit won't get 
saved by the program and it just left out. So, how am i supposed to do with this problem 
 when I want to saved the input?

For example of what I am currently thinking:

```
textField1.getText().{someCodeToRemoveTwoOrOneDigit}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This reads a lot like a code request when you show no effort.

Comment: tried finding in stack overflow but i can't get what i need exactly as it is. -_- sorry.

Comment: I would recommend actually trying to code this yourself first. I rarely find the exact solution for my problem but I usually do find something similar that I'm able to adapt to my scenario. You are asking way too early on the coding process.

Comment: thanks for the advice @tnw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is remove a trailing 1- or 2-digit block, then do this:

```java
text.replaceAll(",\\d{1,2}$", "")
```

```
1,000,000,00   ->  1,000,000
1,000,000,0    ->  1,000,000
1,000,000,000  ->  1,000,000,000
1,00,000,000   ->  1,00,000,000
$1,00,000,000  ->  $1,00,000,000
```

If you want to only retain a "valid" number, i.e. a number with 1-3 leading digits, following by X number of 3-digit blocks, then do this:

```java
text.replaceAll("\\D*(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*)?.*", "$1")
```

```
1,000,000,00   ->  1,000,000
1,000,000,0    ->  1,000,000
1,000,000,000  ->  1,000,000,000
1,00,000,000   ->  1
$1,00,000,000  ->  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, btw if the assumption is that you can't type any non-digit in the program, would this regex "(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)?.*" enough?

Comment: Defensive programming. Assume you can. If not now, maybe later. Things change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression such as `"^(.*),[\\d]{1,2}$"`

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] inp = { "1,000,000,00", "1,000,000,0", "1,000,000", "1,000,000,000" };

    for (String s : inp) {
        System.out.println(s+ " : " + s.replaceAll("^(.*),[\\d]{1,2}$", "$1"));
    }
}
```

Example Output:

> 1,000,000,00 : 1,000,000
>   1,000,000,0 : 1,000,000
>   1,000,000 : 1,000,000
>   1,000,000,000 : 1,000,000,000

Comment: Thanks for the answer @KevinO. Thanks to you now, I get a more understanding of how regex work, at first, I'm confused about your regex, now I'm understand. Thank you.

Comment: That code will do nothing for bad input like this: `1,00,000,000`. Also `[\\d]` is the long way to say `\\d`.

Comment: @Andreas, Yes [\\d] is longer than just \\d, but much like always using curly braces with statements, it is my preference to put character matching in square brackets. It is true the approach will give back the "bad" input of "1,00,000,000", but there was no requirement specified as to what to do in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper method which does this by splitting the string up around commas:

```
public String removeLastDigits(String toTrim) {
 //split up the string based on commas
 String[] trimSplit = toTrim.split(",");
 String toRet = "";

 //loop over every element but the last
 for (int i = 0; i < trimSplit.length() - 1; i++) {
  toRet = toRet + trimSplit[i];
  toRet = toRet + ",";
 }

 //add the last element only if it has more than 2 digits
 String lastElement = trimSplit[trimSplit.length() - 1];
 if (lastElement.length() > 2) {
  //return with the last element
  return (toRet + lastElement);
 } else {
  //strip off the end comma and return
  return toRet.substring(0, toRet.length() - 1);
 }
}
```

This is untested but the structure should be good.